# Predicting continues price data using LinearRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have data of GOLD prices (XAUUSD) since 2017-01-01. My data is in the following format:

```
Timestamp,Close,Open,High,Low
1483304400,1150.52,1150.55,1152.66,1149.66
1483304700,1158.91,1150.71,1163.61,1145.68
1483305000,1163.8,1158.88,1168.23,1155.95
```

I am loading whole data until the last line (excluding the last line) to `X` beginning of 0. To `y`, loading whole data excluding `Timestamp` column only, until the last data but beginning of 1 (first data excluded, last data included). Now I have shifted datas. For example y contains today's prices amd X contains yesterday's prices. And X_real is the prediction. It is the last data and i am going to predict the real unknown data which is tomorrow's prices in this case:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data/xauusd.csv")
X = df[:-1]
X_real = df[-1:]
y = df[["Close", "High", "Low"]][1:]
```

Here comes the confusing part. I am using the LinearRegression model but I am not sure if i am using it correct way and i am not sure if this is the best model to use. Here what i did:

```
lm = LinearRegression()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = lm.score(X_test, y_test)
lm.fit(X, y)
prd = lm.predict(X_real)
```

In last 2 lines, i am fitting X,y (training) and predicting X_real which contains today's prices. Accuracy is as high as 0.99. However prediction is not even close.

Am I using the wrong method or wrong approach? Am i doing something wrong? Or is it what it meant to be? For example i can only get accuracy of the training part and i know it has to be that way but are there any ways to get the accuracy of real data? do i need to, somehow, select the last predict method to use what it learned from training? `fit()` should do this but i am not sure!

One last thing is i think i don't need to use `train_test_split()` method to predict new values do i?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Your features (X) contain time and other 3 columns. Your labels (Y) you want to predict are also have these 3 columns. If you have true knowledge of label already , what is the purpose of predicting? Or, given a timestamp, do you want to predict Close, High, Low values? In this case X should not contain these values.

Comment: Yes i am trying to predict Close, High, Low values but they belong to a different date not the same date. They are just column names.

Comment: Ok, so `X` are yesterday's prices, `y` are today's prices and `X_real` is the last day's price (withheld from the training/test data, to be used for validation). First, I would say that X_real only being 1 row is a very small validation set. Second, have you looked at the result of `lm.predict(X_test)`? You may simply be seeing the result of overfitting - you can fit a nice function to your dataset but it has no predictive power.

Comment: No I haven't checked that. Yes it only have 1 row but entire dataset is also set to run as 1 row. Do you mean checking predict to see the accuracy and calculate and manipulate the real prediction by that values?

Comment: Well I have compared the value returns from predict(X_test) with y_test and the differences are not consistent.